# Why doesn't double pointer modify the table?

Tags: c++, c

I have a question.

This is my structure :

```
typedef struct cell{

    char *mot;
    char *traduction;
    struct cell *suivant;


}cellule_t;
```

This is the main function where I call the function `remplissage_hachage`

```
int main()
{
    char *buffer = "hello";    
    cellule_t **tabMajeur;
    tabMajeur = malloc(HASH_MAX * sizeof(cellule_t *));
    memset(tabMajeur,0 ,HASH_MAX);
    FILE * file = fopen("fichier.txt","r");
    remplissage_hachage(tabMajeur,"fichier.txt");

}
```

The function remplissage_hachage takes tabMajeur as an argument:

```
void remplissage_hachage (cellule_t **tabMajeur,char *nomFichier)
{
    char  string1[20];
    cellule_t *copy;
    unsigned int indice;
    int boolean = 0;
    char *string2, *string3;
    cellule_t *c;


    FILE *fichier= fopen(nomFichier,"r");

    while(fgets(string1,100,fichier) != NULL)
    {
        string2 = strtok(string1,";");
        string3 = strtok(NULL,";"); 
        printf("string2 %s\n",string2);
        printf("string3 %s\n",string3);

        int indice = recherche(tabMajeur,string2,&boolean,c);

        if(boolean != 1) 
        {
            copy = tabMajeur[indice];
            tabMajeur[indice] = creationCellule(string2,string3);
            tabMajeur[indice]->suivant = copy;    
        }


    }

}
```

The problem is that after calling remplissage_hachage in main, tabMajeur is not modified even though I have passed it as a pointer.
 Can you explain to me why please?

Comment: Use your debugger to set a breakpoint on the line that you believe modifies your array, and see if that's true, and if not, use your debugger to figure out why. This is what a debugger is for. P.S. Furthermore, 3/4 of your malloced array is not initialized, and if you win a lottery this will result in undefined behavior, an uninitialized pointer dereference, and a guaranteed crash.

Comment: Avoid double tagging C and C++ unless you have a question that has to do with the differences or interactions between the two languages. This question I would stick to tagging C if for no better reason than to avoid comments like, "You don't have to `typedef struct cell{ ... }cellule_t;` in C++."

Comment: Nothing about this seems to be using C++. Is there a reason for both tags? Are you compiling it as C++ for some reason?

Comment: If you allocate `HASH_MAX * sizeof(cellule_t *)` bytes for pointers, how many bytes do you think you need to set zero with `memset`? `memset(tabMajeur,0 ,HASH_MAX);` is 8x fewer bytes than allocated.

Comment: What is in `copy = tabMajeur[indice];` and where did the storage for `tabMajeur[indice]` come from?

Comment: To start, use `std::vector`, and avoid `malloc` and `new`.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked that boolean!=1 after the call to recherche()?
also you're unnecessarily opening the file twice, once in main() and once in remplissage_hachage().

if 'boolean' has the correct value then the other possible failure point is the while condition which will fail if the file is empty.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer. You do not yet have the ability to make comments, you can thank spammers for that, but making non answers unfortunately can push gaining that privilege further into the future. You may be able to salvage this answer by making your suggestions more concrete and explaining why you have made them